# How would I hide WordPress pages from non-administrators in the Dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, dashboard

I need to hide certain pages in the WordPress Pages Dashboard from anyone who is not an admin, I want to restrict my clients from editing them as these were auto created pages (at theme activation) and are ONLY for templates.

This article [here](https://www.isitwp.com/hide-posts-and-pages-within-the-admin-from-users/) shows how to hide the pages by page/post "ID" but I need to have it done by the page slug or every time someone activates my theme, they will have to dig around for the page IDs to input into the functions.php file.

The 3 pages in this example would have a name or slug of `products`, `policy` and `services`

The below code isn't doing anything for me?

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_posts_pages');

function hide_posts_pages() {
    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    If($current_user->user_login != 'admin') {
        ?>
        <style>
           slug ==> 'products', slug ==> 'policy', slug ==> 'services', {
                display:none;
           }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

~ Any suggestions anyone?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the following function in your functions.php . In `$hidden_slugs` add slugs you want to hide. We need page ids to filter them. Using `get_page_by_path` helps to find ids based on slug.

**Solution 1 with capabilites:**

```
add_filter('parse_query', 'hide_pages_by_slug_if_not_admin');
function hide_pages_by_slug_if_not_admin($query) {
    if(!is_admin()) return;
    
    if( is_admin() && current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        return;
    } else {
        // Create array of all the slugs you wanna hide
        $hidden_slugs = array( 'products', 'policy','services');

        // Loop through slugs & pass each slug as page path value
        foreach ($hidden_slugs as $hidden ) {

            $hidden_slugs[] = get_page_by_path( $hidden )->ID;

        // In case you need to hide the home page too uncomment
        //$hidden_slugs[] += get_option('page_on_front');

        }
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] =  $hidden_slugs;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2 with user role:**

```
add_filter('parse_query', 'hide_pages_by_slug_if_not_admin');
function hide_pages_by_slug_if_not_admin($query) {
    if(!is_admin()) return;

    $user = wp_get_current_user(); // Current user
    $allowed_roles = array('administrator'); // Allowed roles
    
    if( is_admin() && array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {
        return;
    } else {

        // Create array of all the slugs you wanna hide
        $hidden_slugs = array( 'products', 'policy','services');

        // Loop through slugs & pass each slug as page path value
        foreach ($hidden_slugs as $hidden ) {

        $hidden_slugs[] = get_page_by_path( $hidden )->ID;

        // In case you need to hide the home page too uncomment
        // $hidden_slugs[] += get_option('page_on_front');

        }
        // Pass the array as value to the query vars filter 
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] =  $hidden_slugs;
    }
 }
```

Keep in mind that wont prevent them from editing. If someone with permission to edit pages just types in the url wp-admin/post.php?post=postID&action=edit will still be able to edit. The ID of certain post can be found in many ways.

Here is one quick solution you may use to prevent editing those pages:

```
// Prevent access to restricted pages
if(isset($_GET['post'])) {
    $current_postID = $_GET['post'];
    if (in_array($current_postID, $hidden_slugs)) {
        $url=  admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=page';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Add the following after `$query->query_vars['post__not_in'] =  $hidden_slugs;`

Comment: `current_user_can()` can only be used with capabilities not roles.  You should use `current_user_can('manage_options')` or actually check `$user->roles`

Comment: @Martin Mirchev: Thanks so much for your answer, I so appreciate you writing everything out for me and it hides the pages just fine! However when I attempt to delete a page it throws me an error and complains about this line of code here: `if (in_array($current_postID, $hidden_slugs)) {` see screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1qw0xi9 and also here: https://prnt.sc/1qw17k5 and thanks for anymore enlightment!

Comment: @Howard E Could you elaborate in a code snippet please?

Comment: My comment was directed at the answer... He updated his answer accordingly.

Comment: I have tested the code when i delete a page and dont get any errors. The following snipet is just checking if user is not allowed to edit this page to redirect him. Comment the snippet and test if you still get errors. Also i see you have errors in file named pagesetup.php in your theme. I suggest you to move this function in functions.php and test.

Comment: Yes, when I comment out the following code, I get no errors, is there still something missing? `// Prevent access to restricted pages
if(isset($_GET['post'])) {
    $current_postID = $_GET['post'];
    if (in_array($current_postID, $hidden_slugs)) {
        $url=  admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=page';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}`